# jQuery ajax autocomplete not assigning value to hiddenfield

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, jquery-ui

I am having a very strange issue with jQuery autocomplete, please check the script code below

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery1.8-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("[id$=txtSearch]").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/SearchResultsWS.asmx/GetFacilityNames") %>',
                    data: "{ 'prefix': '" + request.term + "'}",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data.d, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.split('*----*')[0],
                                val: item.split('*-----*')[1]
                            }
                        }))
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            },
            select: function (e, i) {
                $("[id$=hfFacilityId]").val(i.item.val);
                //$("[id$=valueText]").text(i.item.val);
                alert(i.item.val);
                //return false;
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[type=text]').click(function () {
            $(this).select();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is the asp.net code

```
<label for="txtSearch" id="SearchLabel" runat="server">Search Reports: </label>
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSearch" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hfFacilityId" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="valueText" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Go!" OnClick="Submit"/>
```

I am loading the autocomplete list from a SQL server database using a web service, everything works fine, except the `$("[id$=hfFacilityId]").val(i.item.val);` and `alert(i.item.val);` statements. 
Nothing is assigned to the hidden field and alert throws "undefined"!!
I tried to troubleshoot this without success. If I use i.Item.label instead of i.item.val it is working fine. So something to do with item.val is not working.

Appreciate any help.. thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not too familiar with this but docs says response is `response( event, ui )`. I think you only have one argument for the response (map).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the following code, you have extra dash `-` in `val: item.split('*-----*')` compared to `label: item.split('*----*')`

```
 return {
          label: item.split('*----*')[0],
          val: item.split('*-----*')[1]
        }
```